# Passing data from view to controler and back to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName"))
{ 
 @Html.Label("Amount")
 @Html.TextBox("txtAmount")
 <input class="button" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
@ViewBag.Average
}
```

And Controller

```
  public ActionResult ActionMethodName(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string input = collection.Get("txtAmount");
        int numberOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join(null, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input, "[^\\d]")));


        //float kwota_rachunku=db.RachunekModel.Select(;

        ViewBag.Average = db.RachunekModel.OrderByDescending(m => m.RachunekID)  // -< typo fixed here!!
                .Take(numberOfItems)
                .Average(m => m.Podatek);
        return View();

    }
```

And simply i want to get average from user input number of elements and send it back to view.
What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Well what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Do you even hit your controller action? You do not specify the controller name in the BeginForm arguments.

Comment: When I input number and hit submit button my site adres change from
http://localhost:11396/Rachunek into http://localhost:11396/Rachunek?Length=16 and thats all.

Comment: So you aren't hitting your controller action?

Comment: I would also suggest that you strongly bind your view to your model instead of using the FormCollection.

Comment: Yes, i was expecting that when i click submit button under this button it will appear ViewBag with my average number.

Comment: Maybe some hints with strongly binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName", "YourControllerName"))
{ 
 @Html.Label("Amount")
 @Html.TextBox("txtAmount")
 <input class="button" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
 @ViewBag.Average
 @Html.Hidden("Average", ViewBag.Average)
}
```

And Controller

```
 public ActionResult ActionMethodName(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string input = collection.Get("txtAmount");
        int numberOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join(null, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input, "[^\\d]")));


        //float kwota_rachunku=db.RachunekModel.Select(;

        ViewBag.Average = db.RachunekModel.OrderByDescending(m => m.RachunekID)  // -< typo fixed here!!
                .Take(numberOfItems)
                .Average(m => m.Podatek);
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: This part isn't working  @Html.Hidden("Average", ViewBag.Average)

Comment: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<App_User.Models.RachunekModels>>' has no applicable method named 'Hidden' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: remove that line and try it again.

Comment: I tried and now it's : "The view 'ActionMethodName' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Comment: and my route also changes to http://localhost:11396/Rachunek/ActionMethodName and i don't have view like this.

Comment: i make a new strongly type view called ActrionMethod name with @ViewBag.Average and now it works :) thx for help all of you.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your view code:

```
@ViewBag.Average
```

Does not assign the Average value anywhere. You should assign it e.g. to a hidden field:

```
@ViewBag.Average
@Html.Hidden("Average", ViewBag.Average)
```

Btw for the future I would recommend you to use strongly-typed views because it makes the whole creation of your views and controller's action much simpler.